# how to count duplicate entry as one in sql

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a column which is `shoes_type`. I need to count the number of shoes_type based on shoes_size,  but some of the shoes_type is duplicated based on color.

I did:

```
select shoes_size, count(shoes_type) from shoes_project
where status_test = 'APPROVED' group by date
```

Perhaps I can use `distinct` to count duplicate type as 1 type, but how I supposed to write my query?

Thanks.

Comment: I don't think that `group by` will work without shoes_size in it... do OP check is this query actually work?

Comment: Your `GROUP BY` makes the query wrong. If a lot of different `shoes_size` matches the same date then one indefinite (randomly) will be returned. Maybe you need in `GROUP BY shoes_size`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> [SQL COUNT()](https://www.w3resource.com/sql/aggregate-functions/count-with-distinct.php) function with DISTINCT clause eliminates the repetitive appearance of the same data. The DISTINCT can come only once in a given select statement.

You can make distinct inside count function

```
select shoes_size, count(DISTINCT shoes_type) as count_shoes from shoes_project
where status_test = 'APPROVED' group by date
```